# How do I install miniconda/anaconda on ARM systems?

Tags: software-installation, python, arm, anaconda

I have a Beaglebone black running on Ubuntu 14. How do I install Anaconda on it?

Answer (score 1):

You can install miniconda to armv7 as shown in this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39371772/how-to-install-anaconda-on-raspberry-pi-3-model-b

Then use "conda" as per norm package management.  It is definitely not as smooth as anaconda for nix64, but many packages are built in alternate channels as "anaconda search -t conda " will show you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Anaconda is closed-source software and Continuum doesn't release any binaries that are suited for ARM processors like the one on the Beaglebone systems.

Answer (score 0):

You can download it from here https://repo.continuum.io/archive/ but be warned: "latest" version is from 2015, which is stupid old.